# c# asynchronous invoke of generic delegates

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, delegates

I want to invoke a general `Delegate` using `async await`. I am not working with a prebuilt delegates, but rather the general `Delegate` class which can receive arguments as an array of objects.

I am doing something like this:

```
public object InvokeAction(Delegate action, object[] actionArgs = null)
    {
        if(action == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return action.DynamicInvoke(args);
    }
```

What I want to do is give an option to run the delegate using `await` but since `DynamicInvoke` returns an object, it doesn't have an `awaiter`.

Is there a way to define a general delegate and make an asynchronous invocation? If not a generic one, is there some version which is close to a generic delegate (It's ok to force the user to some delegate definition) which can be invoked the way I want?

Comment: That `action` delegate -- is that actually going to be asynchronous, i.e. does it return a `Task`?

Comment: can you share an example of the methods to be invoked? I hope you know only because you await something doesn´t make that asynchronous.

Comment: The action can be anything for a regular synchronous call. In case of an asynchronous invocation I'm trying to check if I can still use the same general delegate or do I must define a delegate which returns a task and force the user to use it

Comment: I would suggest a second method `InvokeActionAsync`. Anyway you don´t need to **force** users to use that one, they can of course call your async method without `await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delegate needs to return an [awaitable type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types), generally this is `Task` or `Task<TResult>`.

You could check for this at runtime:

```
public async Task<TResult> InvokeAction<TResult>(Delegate action, object[] actionArgs = null)
{
    //...
    var result = action.DynamicInvoke(actionArgs);
    if (result is Task<TResult> task) return await task;
    return (TResult)result;
}
```

However, as long as `actionArgs` are not modified within your method, you could statically type your delegate, and use a closure:

```
public async Task<TResult> InvokeAction<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> action)
{
    //...
    return await action();
}

var result = InvokeAction(() => YourMethodAsync(arg1, arg2));
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that IF target delegate references to method which is async (returns `Task` or `Task<T>`) then you want to execute it asynchronously. Then you can use method similar to your current one, but which is async:

```
public static async Task<object> InvokeActionAsync(Delegate action, object[] actionArgs = null)
{
    if (action == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // invoke it
    var result = action.DynamicInvoke(actionArgs);
    if (result == null)
        return null;
    if (result.GetType().IsGenericType && result.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>)) {
        // this is some Task<T> which returns result
        await (Task) result;
        // now need to grab the result
        return result.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(result);
    }
    else if (result is Task) {
        // it's regular Task which does not return the value
        await (Task) result;
        return null;
    }
    // otherwise nothing to really run async, just return result
    return result;
}
```